# gulp exclude specific files from uglification

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify

I'm trying to do something like the following. From an array of files that could be either JS or COFFEE, compile the coffee, uglify specific files then concat them all. I don't understand why my filter is not working around the uglify. It seems to work with the coffee  but with uglify filter it just doesn't seem to look at it and just uglifies all the files.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var coffee = require('gulp-coffee');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

var src = [
  'app/assets/1.js',
  'app/assets/2.js',
  'app/assets/components/1.coffee',
  'app/assets/components/2.js',
  'app/assets/utilities/*'
];


var coffeeSrcFilter = $.filter(['*.coffee']);
var minifyExclusionSrcFilter = $.filter(['*', '!app/assets/components/2.js']);


return gulp.src(paths.scripts)
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())

      // coffee
      .pipe(coffeeSrcFilter)
        .pipe(coffee())
      .pipe(coffeeSrcFilter.restore())

      // uglify
      .pipe(minifyExclusionSrcFilter)
        .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(minifyExclusionSrcFilter.restore())

      // concat
      .pipe(gulpConcat('out.js'))

  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});
```

Comment: I just edited above code. it was a gulp script that allowed me to call any gulp-named plugin with $.named automatically.

Comment: I don't see the edit.